# Excel pivot table to recognize dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, pivot-table

I'm sure you all know that when you create a worksheet in Excel which includes dates, and you convert that data into a Pivot Table, excel will very nicely group your dates by Year/Month/Day etc.  When I write a query in MySQL and copy/paste the data to an excel worksheet, Excel refuses to group the dates as it normally would.

I have tried every combination of date_format() in sql that I can think of, as well as tried to mess around with Excel's standard and custom dates once the data has been pasted.  Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Thanks!!

Comment: how about using a formula to convert the date in another column `=Text(A1,"mm-dd-yyyy")` comes to mind, or perhaps `=Date(Year(Right(A1,4),Mid(A1,2,2),Left(A1,2))`. All references and functions are based on hypothetical data but can be manipulated against your actual data in a way that makes sense.

Comment: Show us the string you are trying to convert.